# Create new unknown method in ggts

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, ggts

In "regular" eclipse i'm able to press ctrl(command)-1 on an unknown method and one of the refactor suggestion would be to create it, I can't emulate this behavior in ggts, am I missing something ?

Comment: In Java code or in Groovy code? It should work in Java code, but not all quickfixes are implemented for Groovy. If it doesn't work for Java code its most likely a bug and you might consider reporting it here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: I am not 100% certain but I don't think that particular quickfix is supported in groovy code. I did a search for quickfix related issues in the Greclipse issue tracker (https://jira.codehaus.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22quickfix%22%20AND%20project%3DGRECLIPSE). You could open a issue ticket to ask for this particular quickfix it to be implemented.

Comment: Careful... I posted wrong issue tracker link in comments above (but can no no longer edit it). Issues for greclipse go in the greclipse tracker, not the STS one. So this one: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE

Comment: @Kris how can I open there new tickets ? I don't have any permissions

Comment: You have to singup to access the tracker, this is a bit confusing as you actually have to signup for 'xircles' account and lots of people are confused by the messages on the jira tracker that make this rather non-obvious (see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/HAUS-2323)